# erlang.mk buildtool is unable to detect windows

Tags: windows, erlang, cowboy

I have build a website with Erlang and Cowboy with ErlyDTL on a Linux OS.
Now I want that my website can run on Windows and want to use the Erlang.mk with Relx build tool.

When I give the make command it gives me the error:

> Unable to detect platform. Please open a ticket with the output of
>   uname -a.

uname -a output:

> MINGW32_NT-6.2 LENOVO-... 2012-11-21 22:34 i686 Msys

How can I fix this problem in a easy way with explanation because I don't know much of makefiles ;).

**Specs:**

I have Windows 8.1 64 bit OS.
My Erlang.mk is version 1.2.0-634-g2f69190.

I installed MinGW with msys so I can run `make` and `make distclean`.
I have the following extra packages installed during this intallation:

- mingw-developer-toolkit
- mingw32-base
- mingw32-gcc-g++
- msys-base

So the PATH to MinGW is c:\MinGW.
With CMD I started `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat`
Then with the bash shell I ran de postinstall script `pi.sh`. This gave me no errors.

Then I have installed some extra packages for MinGW with success:

- mingw-get install msys-rxvt
- mingw-get install msys-unzip
- mingw-get install msys-zip
- mingw-get install msys-wget

I have red https://github.com/ninenines/erlang.mk/issues/294 but I couldn't understand what I have to do because the lack of explanation.

So is there a solution? If yes what is it and please give some explanation with it so I can fix my problem and understand what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance